# how can I update linestring on postgis?

Tags: postgis

I have a linestring on my postgis.
and I want to add a new point linestring. I mean I want to update my linestring?
how can ı do this?

```
UPDATE roads SET geom = ST_AddPoint(geom, 'POINT(0,0)') WHERE id =9;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a geometry object, rather than just the text representation.

`UPDATE roads SET geom = ST_AddPoint(geom, ST_MakePoint(0,0)) WHERE id = 9;`

That will work if you want to add the point to the *end* of the line. If you want to add it as the *n*th vertex, you would use the optional third parameter. For example, if you want to add your point as the third vertex:

`UPDATE roads SET geom = ST_AddPoint(geom, ST_MakePoint(0,0), 2) WHERE id = 9;`

Note that the position parameter (2 above) is a zero-based index. So to add a new start point, you would use 0.